# TeamCity - scheduled build not starting

Tags: teamcity

I've posted this question on the TC discussion forum but so far haven't received any response, so decided to try my luck here.

Recently I started seeing very strange behavior and would appreciate any ideas what may be going wrong.
I'm using version 7.1 (build 23907) on the internal database.
I have two builds (dev and release) using single build template. So the all steps, parameters and the build trigger is defined in the template, specific builds only change checkout branches etc.

So this setup has been working just fine, triggered on schedule every day. But recently one of the builds stopped working. Changes are pooled correctly for both builds (if I use trigger on pending changes option) but only one build gets triggered and run.
Of course everything works fine with a manual run but the problem is that the build never gets triggered.

I've added one more trigger to the problematic build only (not to the template), again, simple scheduled trigger, but still nothing, the build doesn't get started...

Any clues or directions where should I try looking would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do have the "Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer" check box checked in your trigger config?

I had a similar problem and when I unchecked that option everything started working.