# Scheduled TeamCity build doesn't run

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have tried to set up a scheduled TeamCity trigger but have run into problems.

My scenario is that apart from my unit tests I also have a much slower integration test suite that takes app. 20 mins to run.

While I would love to run that on every GitHub pull request check-in as I do with my unit tests it just doesn't scale. So the second best thing is to run it nightly on all my GitHub pull requests.

So I set up a Scheduled trigger that runs daily at 01.00 with a branch filter `+:refs/pull/*/head`. I also tried `+:refs/pull/*/merge`.

But it doesn't trigger any builds... and I can't figure out why. I can manually start a build on any of my pull requests, and when the build is done it reports back to GitHub just as expected.

I don't have the "Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer" check box checked as suggested here [TeamCity - scheduled build not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320818/teamcity-scheduled-build-not-starting).

All input on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've set up a schedule trigger and not a VCS trigger? I ask because the "Include several check-ins....." option is only available for VCS triggers.

Comment: Good point, I guess I have tried out several different things and confused myself. It is a schedule trigger, and the option mentioned is on a VCS trigger.

Comment: OK. In that case I'd make sure that the "Trigger only if there are pending changes" option is unchecked because that will stop the build being triggered if it doesn't detect any pending changes. Other than that I would have a look in the agent logs to see if you can see if it's even trying to start

Comment: Based on your branch filter outlined above, I assume you're using Git?  I'd try just running on the default branch for sanity checking:  +:<default>

Comment: Yes I am using git. I can get a schedule trigger to fire on +:<default> and I can get a VCS trigger to fire on +:<default>, but not on +:refs/pull/*/head even though I can trigger them manually. Will check the logs if I can find them.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this yet, as i have the same problem at the moment, however it did work for a few months before.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that someone else here at my company solved it for me, and that was good enough for me. I never got the full explanation of what he did.